# How to use .catch() correctly? Unable to use it in certain code

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

when i run my schedule code to post message, each time the message is sent i receive this error message:

**Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)**

Code below does not use `try {` in the beginning, but even with this i got the same error message ..

```
'use strict';

const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

class AutoMsgController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController {
    AutoMsgHandler(scope) {
        console.log(scope);
        if (statement) {
            const button = {'inline_keyboard': [
                [{ text: 'BUTTON1', url: 'URL1' }],
                [{ text: 'BUTTON2', url: 'URL2' }]
            ]}
            const parsedbutton = JSON.stringify(button);
            console.log(parsedbutton);
            scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, '*ACTIVATED!*', { 'parse_mode' : 'Markdown'});
            var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * * *', function(){ //5 Seconds
            scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, 'My message'
            ).then (
            function (e) {
                console.log ('Could not send automsg', e);
                throw e;
              }
            );
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Api call error:', err.message)
      });
    }
}
    get routes() {
        return {
            'AutoMsgCommand': 'AutoMsgHandler'
        };
    }
}

module.exports = AutoMsgController;
```

If i try to use `try {` im unable to finish, it says : `finally expected`

```
'use strict';

const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

class AutoMsgController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController {
    AutoMsgHandler(scope) {
        console.log(scope);
        if (statement) {
            try {
            const button = {'inline_keyboard': [
                [{ text: 'BUTTON1', url: 'URL1' }],
                [{ text: 'BUTTON2', url: 'URL2' }]
            ]}
            const parsedbutton = JSON.stringify(button);
            console.log(parsedbutton);
            scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, '*ACTIVATED!*', { 'parse_mode' : 'Markdown'});
            var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * * *', function(){ //5 Seconds
            scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, 'My message'
            ).then (
            function (e) {
                console.log ('Could not send automsg', e);
                throw e;
              }
            );
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Api call error:', err.message)
      });
    }
  } //<- here is the problem `finally expected`
}
    get routes() {
        return {
            'AutoMsgCommand': 'AutoMsgHandler'
        };
    }
}

module.exports = AutoMsgController;
```

Can't figure it out... from other posts i was not able to find answer.

Even in this case it will drop the same thing...

```
'use strict';

const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

class AutoMsgController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController {
    AutoMsgHandler(scope) {
        console.log(scope);
        if (statement) {
            try {
            const button = {'inline_keyboard': [
                [{ text: 'BUTTON1', url: 'URL1' }],
                [{ text: 'BUTTON2', url: 'URL2' }]
            ]}
            const parsedbutton = JSON.stringify(button);
            console.log(parsedbutton);
            scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, '*ACTIVATED!*', { 'parse_mode' : 'Markdown'});
            var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * * *', function(){ //5 Seconds
            scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, 'My message'
            ).then (
            function (e) {
                console.log ('Could not send automsg', e);
                throw e;
              }
            );
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Api call error:', err.message)
      });
        catch (error) {
        console.log('Api call error:', error)
      }
    }
}
    get routes() {
        return {
            'AutoMsgCommand': 'AutoMsgHandler'
        };
    }
}

module.exports = AutoMsgController;
```

```
'use strict';

const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

class AutoMsgController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController {
    AutoMsgHandler(scope) {
        console.log(scope);
        if (statement) {
            try {
            const button = {'inline_keyboard': [
                [{ text: 'BUTTON1', url: 'URL1' }],
                [{ text: 'BUTTON2', url: 'URL2' }]
            ]}
            const parsedbutton = JSON.stringify(button);
            console.log(parsedbutton);
            scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, '*ACTIVATED!*', { 'parse_mode' : 'Markdown'});
            var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * * *', function(){ //5 Seconds
            scope.api.sendPhoto(scope.message._chat._id, 'My Message'
            ).then (
                function (e) {
                    console.log ('Could not send automsg', e);
                    throw e;
                  }
                );
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('Api call error:', err.message)
          });         
        } catch (error) {
        console.log('Api call error:', error)
      }
    }
}
    get routes() {
        return {
            'AutoMsgCommand': 'AutoMsgHandler'
        };
    }
}

module.exports = AutoMsgController;
```

Made progress with this code 
**Api call error: TypeError: schedule.scheduleJob(...).catch is not a function**

**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 5)**

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to place a `catch` or `finally` block after the try, as well as using `then` rather than `catch` for error handling.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Also, you should look at what the error is that is being thrown, since an error indicates a failed transaction.

```
'use strict';

const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

class AutoMsgController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController {
    AutoMsgHandler(scope) {
        console.log(scope);
        if (statement) {
            try {
            const button = {'inline_keyboard': [
                [{ text: 'BUTTON1', url: 'URL1' }],
                [{ text: 'BUTTON2', url: 'URL2' }]
            ]}
            const parsedbutton = JSON.stringify(button);
            console.log(parsedbutton);
            scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, '*ACTIVATED!*', { 'parse_mode' : 'Markdown'});
            var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * * *', function(){ //5 Seconds
            scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, 'My message'
            ).then(function (response) {
                // Do something with the response
            }).catch (
            function (e) {
                console.log ('Could not send automsg', e);
                throw e; // This still throws the same warning, but could be useful
              }
            );
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Api call error:', err.message)
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Do error handling stuff
  }
}
    get routes() {
        return {
            'AutoMsgCommand': 'AutoMsgHandler'
        };
    }
}

module.exports = AutoMsgController;
```

Comment: 'try' expected.

Comment: Unfortunately now it says ```finally``` and ```try``` are expected..

Comment: ```
        catch (error) {
        console.log('Api call error:', error)
      }
    }
}
```

No issue with code itself... but still after launching schedule i got the same thing **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 13)**

Comment: Just realized you used a `then` method, which executes on successful for error handling on line 27, fixed answer.

Comment: Tried your new answer, try' expected.also with 'finally' expected.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
const Telegram = require("telegram-node-bot");
var schedule = require("node-schedule");

class AutoMsgController extends Telegram.TelegramBaseController {
  AutoMsgHandler(scope) {
    console.log(scope);
    if (statement) {
      try {
        const button = {
          inline_keyboard: [
            [{ text: "BUTTON1", url: "URL1" }],
            [{ text: "BUTTON2", url: "URL2" }],
          ],
        };
        const parsedbutton = JSON.stringify(button);
        console.log(parsedbutton);
        scope.api.sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, "*ACTIVATED!*", {
          parse_mode: "Markdown",
        });
        var j = schedule
          .scheduleJob("*/5 * * * * *", function () {
            //5 Seconds
            scope.api
              .sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, "My message")
              .then(function (e) {
                console.log("Could not send automsg", e);
                throw e;
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("sendMessage call error:", error.message);
                throw error;
              });;
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Api call error:", error);
      }
    }
  }
  get routes() {
    return {
      AutoMsgCommand: "AutoMsgHandler",
    };
  }
}

module.exports = AutoMsgController;
```

Comment: I made the progress, this also works :-) the error is:

**Api call error: TypeError: schedule.scheduleJob(...).catch is not a function

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 5)**

Comment: maybe "schedule.scheduleJob" doesnt' return a promise, try with 
var j = schedule
          .scheduleJob("*/5 * * * * *", function () {
            //5 Seconds
            scope.api
              .sendMessage(scope.message._chat._id, "My message")
              .then(function (e) {
                console.log("Could not send automsg", e);
                throw e;
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("sendMessage call error:", error.message);
                throw error;
              });
          })

I mean without the catch

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the value of `j` is declared but its value is never read. I did not found the way how to make the `j` to be read to catch error correctly.. That's probably why i have this .catch warning all the time..